# grab domain name and expiry date from string

Tags: php, php-5.3

I want to grab domain name and expiry date from following string...

```
'2011-09-25,$69,climatelawpolicy.net'
```

can you help me to write regex to grab doman and date from above using php. thanks.

Comment: oh right, i could use explode simple, but i was thinking to use preg_match();

Answer (score 3):

Simply you can `explode(',' , '2011-09-25,$69,climatelawpolicy.net')`

Full code:

```
$arr=explode(',' , '2011-09-25,$69,climatelawpolicy.net')
echo $arr['0']; //date
echo '<br/>';
echo $arr['2']; //domain
```

Comment: oh right, i could use explode simple, but i was thinking to use preg_match();

Answer (score 1):

I have used explode for this instead of preg_match

$str = '2011-09-25,$69,climatelawpolicy.net';

```
$expiring = explode(',', $str);

echo 'Date: '.$expiring[0];
echo 'Domain: '.$expiring[2];
```

simple using `explode()`